# How to import jar file in jython?

Tags: jython

heres what ive tried

***TRIED***

```
import sys
import os
lib = os.getcwd() + os.sep + "lib" + os.sep + "JDA-5.0.0-alpha.18-withDependencies.jar"
sys.path.append(lib)
from net.dv8tion.jda.core import JDABuilder as Builder

#jda = Builder("TOKEN").build()
```

i get cant import module net

***JAVA SIDE***

```
package xyz.chatterbx;


import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;

import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.Objects;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File f = new File("python");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.mkdir();

        } else {
            File folder = new File("python");
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
                if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                    String file = listOfFiles[i].getAbsolutePath();
                    PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
                    interpreter.execfile(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***ERROR***

```
2 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 1 up-to-date
Exception in thread "main" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\java\bot\disc\bot\python\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from net.dv8tion.jda.core import JDABuilder as Builder
ImportError: No module named net

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':Main.main()'.
> Process 'command 'C:/Users/michael/.jdks/openjdk-18.0.2.1/bin/java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

That's everything its not picking up the jar file and I don't know why I tried just referencing the lib folder but that didnt work

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question lacks some details: what exact command did you enter, and what was the exact error message. And please take some time to read some of this: [ask].

Comment: is that better?